# jquery validator error display issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am observing some strange behavior. Under some circumstances including, if I call valid on any of the fields, the way *"This field is required"* is displayed changes. Why is this happening? Perhaps any kind of error on the page?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The `[!]` is the browser's built-in validation. `This field is required` comes from jquery-validate.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.  The way the jQuery Validate plugin works, it's impossible to see HTML5 validation popups mixed with jQuery Validate messages on the same form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message `This field is required` comes from `jquery-validate.js`, which runs when you call `.valid()`.

The messasge `[!] Please select an item in the list` comes from the browser's built-in validation when you have the `required` attribute in the element. It does this check when the form is being submitted.

If you don't want the browser's validation, don't put attributes like `required` in the HTML. `jquery-validate` understands `class="required"`, or you can put the specification of which fields are required in the rules when you initialize the plugin:

```
$("#formid").validate({
    rules: {
        customer: "required",
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this must be it. I am fairly new to this appreciate your help. I do like the browser default display? What is the preferred/recommended way to do validation? jquery validator or browser? I was mixing them up apparently. Using different validators for different fields ok? I guess look wise not that great...

Comment: `jquery-validator` gives you lots of validation options that the browser doesn't have, including the ability to create custom validation rules. It also provides lots of customization features, so you can provide your own messages, and control how they're displayed. So it depends on how much you want to do.

Comment: that is exactly why I added it in a first place. just could not figure out inconsistency. the way messages are displayed are not great of course. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to be clear, when using the jQuery Validate plugin, the `novalidate` attribute is added to the `form` automatically.  In other words, you would only get the HTML5 popup if jQuery Validate is not installed and initialized.  Also, the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically handle the `required` attribute exactly the same as the `required` class.

Comment: @Sparky I forgot about that `novalidate` attribute. I wonder why he's seeing the built-in message, then. I know that it handles the `required` attribute, I was just showing how to tell `jquery-validate` that it's required in a way that the browser won't notice.

Comment: I was actually returning here to discuss this same issue. I have no idea how I was getting built-in message and why I could not reproduce it anymore, which is explained by what Sparky just said. It also makes sense why I am getting messages using required and not class="required"! Thank you guys.